# PhoneGap - Error code 5 when trying copy file to dataDirectory, but why?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, html5-filesystem

In my app user can choose a image from gallery, this image will be used in "user details". So, a screen was created, him exists an input file named "file". I need copy the image chosen to externalDataDirectory.

My problem is how to get URI from file choosen to make a copy?

My code is... But every time get error code 9, but I don't know what this mean.

```
inputFile = $( '.file' ).val();

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL( cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function( myFileEntry ){


    window.requestFileSystem( LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileEntry){

        parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry( inputFile );


        myFileEntry.getDirectory( "TRETA", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(dir){ 

            // copy the file to a new directory and rename it
            fileEntry.root.copyTo( dir, "arquivo", function(entry){
                console.log("New Path: " + entry.fullPath);
            }, function(error){
                console.log(error);
            });

        }, fail); 


    }, function(error){
        console.log( error );
    });

}, fail);
```

fffff

Answer (score 4):

(Note: Assuming that you want to copy a file that lies in your app-root folder. Lets name it `appURI`).

I can only speak for myself but `LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT` points to `file:///storage/emulated/0/` with my android-phone (test-environment). With this base-URI you have no read/write permission by default, but in its subfolders.

Ths folder you want to access should look like this: `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE/` (`appURI`)

At this folder you have got read/write permission. So you can either use own logic to get this url on your own or you can also use `LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY` that points to `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE/cache/` with my android-phone so I guess it should be the same with you.

But all together:

```
function getAppURI(callback) {
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, function (filesystem) {
    var cacheDir = filesystem.root.toURL();
    var startPointCacheFolderName = cacheDir.match(/\/\w+\/$/) [0];
    callback(cacheDir.replace(startPointCacheFolderName, '') + '/');
  }, function (error) {
    console.log('no access to app-filesystem');
  }
  );
}
```

And finally we can use the right `appURI`:

```
getAppURI(function (appURI) {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(appURI, function (fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.getFile('fileToCopy.txt', {
      create: false, // try true first to make sure that there are no other problems around
      exclusive: false
    }, function (fileEntry) {
      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(appURI+"NAME_OF_A_SUBFOLDER_YOU_WANT_TO_COPY_TO OTHERWISE_REPLACE_THIS_STRING", function (newFileEntry) {
        fileEntry.copyTo(newFileEntry, 'CopiedFile.txt', function (result) {
          console.log("save successfully:", result);
        }, function (err) {
          console.log("err-fileEntry.copyTo: ",err);
        });
      }, function (err) {
        console.log("err-window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL: ",err);
      });
    }, function (err) {
      console.log("err-fileSystem.getFile: ",err);
    });
  }, function (err) {
    console.log("err-resolveLocalFileSystemURL: ",err);
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

Its also worth to mention that error-codes not always indicate the real reason for why a operation could not succeed. With this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46283485/2401386) there was also a read/write-permission error as well as the error-code (`ENCODING_ERR 5`) was the same (have a look at the comments).

Comment: Your explanation help a lot, but again I can't get file from input... in logs I get this...
appURI = file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/br.com.johnhenrique.myapp/
Is right

URI to file choosen in input file: C:\fakepath\IMG-20170926-WA0065.jpg

I just using Android Phone (Android 6.1) but every time get "C:\fakepath...".

If I understand correctly I need replace 'fileToCopy.txt' by "$( '.file' ).val()", is right?

Comment: Thanky. yes, exactly, fileToCopy should be replaced with $('.file').val() as well as CopiedFile with "arquivo", if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I have other problem, is not working, every get error "err-fileSystem.getFile: {code:1}", I just replace as said before...

Comment: the fileToCopy or the path to this file ($('.file').val()) must be stored on your android-device otherwise it will not work. error-code 1 says NOT_FOUND_ERR, so this file does not exist on your device.

Comment: Yes, you is right. But the file is in local storage from Android (exists in device), I just add console.log to see what info is received and I don't know why every time files URI are displayed with "C:\fakepath" (I'm using Google Chrome Inspect).

Comment: All right. Its defently a wrong filename respectively path. 'CopiedFile.txt' should only be replaced with a filename without C:\... when this files is stored in the app-root-folder it should work. Have you tried the shell-command "adb shell" to look after this file? By using Goggle-Inspect tool you can not check whether this file is really stored where is should. Good luck!

Comment: I tried shell-command, no file was copied, but they exists on device.  :-(

Comment: I believe you that this file exists on your device, but the path to it is wrong that's why it can not be copied. You have to put this file into your app-root-folder or into one of it's subfolders. That's the last advice I can give you, sorry. I've inserted a string ("NAME_OF_A_SUBFOLDER...") that represents the sub-folder-name ("TRETA")

Comment: Can you test this in your device? Here all files display path as "C:\fakepath\..." this is my real problem now. Device conected or not at computer.

http://jsfiddle.net/0tfp6ey7/1/

Comment: You can not do this in this way. In one of my answers a pdf file is copied. have y look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46477864/2401386).